# Not able to fetch the 'mobile' attribute from Active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

Following code is working fine. but its not returning 'mobile' attribute from the AD. not getting wats the issue . its returns HomePhone and telephonenumber but not 'mobile' attribute. but when i update it through code its getting update. but not able to read.

```
    DirectoryEntry de = createDirectoryEntry();

   DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
   deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
   deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homePhone");
   deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile");

    //"userPrincipalName", "cn", "homePhone", "mobile", "telephoneNumber", "givenName", "sn"

    deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(userPrincipalName=" + username + "))";
    SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();

    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {
        ResultPropertyCollection props = result.Properties;
        foreach (string propName in props.PropertyNames)
        {
           //Loop properties and pick out company,department
           string tmp = (string)props[propName][0];
        }
    }
```